# What did I do wrong in the code? The registration code does not work, an error in the console

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

What did I do wrong in the code? The registration code does not work, an error in the console
Data is not sent to the database

This script.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".save").click(function(){
        let user = {
            name: $(".name").val(),
            surname: $(".surname").val(),
            age: $(".age").val(),
            gender: $(".input[name='gender']:checked").val(),
            email: $(".email").val(),
            password: $(".password").val(),
            confirm: $(".confirm").val()
        }
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "server.php",
            data: {user: user, action: "ajax1"},
            success: function(r){
                console.log(r); 
                if(r == 1){
                    console.log(r);
                    location.reload;
                }else{
                    r = JSON.parse(r);
                if("error_name" in r){
                    $(".name").val("");
                    $(".name").attr("placeholder", r.error_name);
                }
                if("error_surname" in r){
                    $(".surname").val("");
                    $(".surname").attr("placeholder", r.error_surname);
                }
                if("error_age" in r){
                    $(".age").val("");
                    $(".age").attr("placeholder", r.error_age);
                }
                if("error_email" in r){
                    $(".email").val("");
                    $(".email").attr("placeholder", r.error_email);
                }
                if("error_password" in r){
                    $(".password").val("");
                    $(".password").attr("placeholder", r.error_password);
                }
                if("error_password" in r){
                    $(".confirm").val("");
                    $(".confirm").attr("placeholder", r.error_confirm);
                }
                }
                }
            })
        })
    })
```

This console error

```
script.js:17 
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.success (script.js:22:30)
    at c (jquery.min.js:2:28327)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2:29072)
    at l (jquery.min.js:2:79901)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:2:82355)
```

When I click on Sign up, it gives this error, everything seems to be fine everywhere.
I understand a little about JS

this server.php

```
<?php
    
class Controller{
    function __construct(){
        if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] = "POST"){
            $this->db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'Levon');
            if(isset($_POST['action'])){
                if($_POST['action'] == "ajax1"){
                    $this->addUser();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    function addUser(){
        extract($_POST['user']);
        $error = [];
        if(empty($name)){
            $error['error_name'] = "Fill the name";
        }
        if(empty($surname)){
            $error['error_surname'] = "Fill the surname";
        }
        if(empty($age)){
            $error['error_age'] = "Fill the age";
        }else if(filter_var($age, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT)){
            $error['error_age'] = "Write age correctly";
            }
        if(empty($email)){
            $error['error_email'] = "Fill the Email";
        }else if(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
            $error['error_email'] = "Write Email correctly";
            }
        if(empty($gender)){
            $error['error_gender'] = "Select the gender";     
        }
        if(empty($password)){
            $error['error_password'] = "Select the password";
        }else if(strlen($password) < 6){
                $error['error_password'] = "Password is less than 6";
    
            }
        if(empty($confirm)){
            $error['error_confirm'] = "Fill the page";
        }
        if($password !== $confirm){
            $error['error_confirm'] = "Password didn`t metch";
        }
        if(count($error) > 0){
            print json_encode($error);
        }else{
            $hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
            password_verify($password, $hash);
            $this->db->query("INSERT INTO `users` (`name`, `surname`, `age`, `gender`, `email`, `password`) VALUES ('$name', '$surname', '$age', '$gender', '$email', '$password');");
            print 1;
        }
        new Controller();
    }
}
```

Comment: _an error in the console_ So tell us what the error was

Comment: Your `server.php` is not returning valid JSON. We don't know what it is returning, so we can't really help you much further.

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) 
and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), 
then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), 
the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and 
how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You might try adding the PHP code to your question

Comment: Look in the browser's network tool when you run the ajax request. Click on the ajax request, go to the Response tab, and see what the server is actually returning (instead of the valid JSON you're apparently expecting). Then go to your PHP code and debug it to try and understand why that's happening.

Comment: Please [edit] the question when you have more info. Do not put it into comments or answers. See [ask] and the [tour] (and the rest of the help centre) if you're unsure how Stackoverflow works.

Comment: ___Unexpected end of JSON input___ So the PHP code is sending an Incomplete JSONString! So you/we need to look at the PHP code so we can work out why that is happening. I guess you are trying the write a JSONString manually, thats always dangerous

Comment: I want to send you server.php but I can't throw it in the comments because there are a lot of characters there. For this I throw in the question

Comment: I added php code to the question can you help?

Comment: `print 1;` Thats NOT JSON

Comment: No actually I added the code to the question

Comment: RiggsFolly I'm sorry I tried, but I got an error that a lot of code

Comment: So that's why you have to add more description as well...did you do what I said and actually look at what the code is really returning?

Comment: `new Controller();` is within the method `addUser()`. So if that is the only way you intended to instantiate the class, it will never be instantiated. If you are instantiating it outside the class, thats what you should be doing, then you dont need that line of code there

Comment: P.S. Your code is inconsistent, which is a bad thing. It returns JSON in some cases and just a number in other cases. That makes it harder for the client-side to process the response accurately. It would be a lot better if it returns JSON in all scenarios.

Comment: @ADyson I believe *just a number* is valid JSON. You're welcome to prove otherwise

Comment: @Bravo I'm aware of that. Perhaps I phrased my point poorly. What I meant was it would be better if the code returned a consistent _structure_ , e.g. perhaps a JSON object containing a "status" field showing true or false, so the caller knows if there were problems, and then either a general "message" field for some user-oriented output, and/or an "errors" object/array showing error messages if necessary. Up to the OP obviously, but would be cleaner and clearer for the client-side processing code to deal with. Anyway of course it's probably irrelevant to whatever actual problem is occurring.

Answer (score 1):

Server.php is poorly designed. You should always aim to have a consistent result or in this case a consistent output

Lots of comments inline with the code to describe the changes made and why

```
<?php
    
class Controller{

    function __construct(){
        #
        # It would be better to connect once in the main process 
        # and inject the connection into objects that require it
        #
        if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] = "POST"){
            $this->db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'Levon');
            if(isset($_POST['action'])){
                if($_POST['action'] == "ajax1"){
                    $this->addUser();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    function addUser(){
        // this is a dangerous practice to get into
        // instead, you have a perfectly good array called $_POST, use it!
        extract($_POST['user']);

        $error = [];
        if(empty($name)){
            $error['error_name'] = "Fill the name";
        }
        if(empty($surname)){
            $error['error_surname'] = "Fill the surname";
        }
        if(empty($age)){
            $error['error_age'] = "Fill the age";
        }else if(filter_var($age, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT)){
            $error['error_age'] = "Write age correctly";
            }
        if(empty($email)){
            $error['error_email'] = "Fill the Email";
        }else if(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
            $error['error_email'] = "Write Email correctly";
            }
        if(empty($gender)){
            $error['error_gender'] = "Select the gender";     
        }
        if(empty($password)){
            $error['error_password'] = "Select the password";
        }else if(strlen($password) < 6){
            $error['error_password'] = "Password is less than 6";
        }
        if(empty($confirm)){
            $error['error_confirm'] = "Fill the page";
        }
        if($password !== $confirm){
            $error['error_confirm'] = "Password didn`t metch";
        }
        if(count($error) > 0){
            // consistent return values, so add the status here too.
            print json_encode(['status' => 0, $error);

        }else{
            // hashing the password is GREAT, but you do then actually have to 
            // save this value to the password column in the database
            $hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

            // this line has no function in a create user situation
            //password_verify($password, $hash);

            // this is an SQL Injection nightmare see note at bottom
            //$this->db->query("INSERT INTO `users` (`name`, `surname`, `age`, `gender`, `email`, `password`) VALUES ('$name', '$surname', '$age', '$gender', '$email', '$password');");


            $sql = 'INSERT INTO `users` 
                            (`name`, `surname`, `age`, `gender`, `email`, `password`) 
                    VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)';

            $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
            // bind values to the `?` parameters, note, I bound $hash and not $password
            $stmt->bind_param('ssisss', $name, $surname, $age, 
                                        $gender, $email, $hash );
            $stmt->execute();

            // this is your problem, this is not JSON you are returning
            //print 1;

            // send back a JSON structure
            echo json_encode(['status'=>1]);

        }
        // does nothing sensible here
        //new Controller(); 
    }
}

$obj = new Controller;
```

Now you will need to amend the javascript

```
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "server.php",
            // tell jquery to convert response from JSON String 
            /// to a JS Object automatically
            dataType: "json",       
            
            data: {user: user, action: "ajax1"},
            success: function(r){
                if(r.status == 1){
                    // this is your error situation
                    console.log(r);
                    location.reload;
                } else {
                . . .
```

> [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174).
> Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187)
> You should always use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)
> in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO

Comment: Minor typo: `'surname` :-)

Comment: :) :) Too cryptic @ADyson, feel free to do a mod yourself. Thanks

Comment: :) :) :) FOUND IT :) @ADyson